# Does the Entity Framework code first support readonly navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, properties, navigation, code-first, readonly

Currently I use Entity Framework code first to create my domain models. As the code below illustrates, I want create a one-to-many association between "Test2" class and "Test1" class. But when I ran the application, it threw an exception:

> The navigation property 'T2' is not a declared property on type
>   'Test1'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the
>   model and that it is a valid navigation property.

If I modify the navigation property "T2" to make it have a "protected" or public setter. It is OK. So it seems that the Entity framework does not support the readonly navigation properties. Could anyone explain and give some links for this problem?

```
public abstract class Test1Base
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public virtual Test2 T2 {get; private set;}   
} 

public class Test1 : Test1Base
{

}

public class Test2
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test1> Test1Table {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Test2> Test2Table {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Test1>().HasRequired(t => t.T2).WithMany();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably some minor limitation in code first which is not caused by a private setter but by the private setter in the base class and mapping of the derived class. If you move the `T2` declaration from `Test1Base` to `Test1` it will work with private setter but if you want to leave it in `Test1Base` make the setter protected.

Comment: Yes. I have to make the setter visible in the derived class.

Comment: We already have a bug in this area that won't get fixed until post-EF5. I'll follow up on this and make sure it is covered by that bug or file a new bug as appropriate.