# The key component 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'TypeName', when using base class and private setter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I want to use an abstract base class for entities, which is not mapped on any table:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Since `Id` will be auto-increment, I don't want to allow to change this property from outside. Hence, its setter is `private`.

Here's a sample entity type:

```
public class Order : Entity
{
    public virtual string Customer { get; set; }
}
```

...configuration types:

```
public class EntityConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity
{
    public EntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.Id);
        Property(o => o.Id).HasColumnName("id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class OrderConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderConfiguration()
    {
        Property(o => o.Customer).HasColumnName("customer");
        ToTable("Customers");
    }
}
```

...and context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderConfiguration());
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I'm trying to query orders like this:

```
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            foreach (var order in context.Orders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(order.Customer);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting an exception:

> The key component 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'Order'.
>   Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and
>   that it is a valid primitive property.

I've read several questions at SO, and found, that my approach looks correct. Then, I've modified base class a little and made `Id` with *public* setter:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And (it's a miracle!) the sample code works fine. Also, it works fine without base `Entity` class (when `Id` is defined in `Order`) with private setter.

Logic tells me, that is a buggy behavior of EF.
But, may be, I'm missing something?

Comment: did you try protected setter? I see your point and have just left mine as public as setting it externally doesnt bother me.

Comment: @soadyp: thanks, excellent comment. I've tried it, and it works well too, and, may be, it will be a suitable workaround for me. But I still can't understand the logic of that behavior (and EF team) and consider this as a bug. You should post this as an answer, definitely.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268062/does-the-entity-framework-code-first-support-readonly-navigation-property. From the comments on the answer it seems this is really a bug...

Comment: @nemesv: thanks for the link, and yes, the problem it points looks similar. Well, EF issue tracker waits for me. :)

Comment: +1 nemesv for linking relevant post.  I will add this to answer as it is relevant for those researching.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF likes to access all keys. Try using **protected** so the assembly can access the ID but externals cant. Seems like a reasonable question for the EF team to me.

See related post [Does the Entity Framework code first support readonly navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268062/does-the-entity-framework-code-first-support-readonly-navigation-property)

Answer (score 0):

make setter of id in entity class protected :

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

i tried this . it will be work