# Entity framework DB first - private setter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

For every table, EF generates a partial class, where all fields are publicly accessible, for example

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to make the `set` private? I would then only allow the field to be changed calling my custom public method.

Comment: Simply No. Yes if `T4` templates are applied.

Comment: Do you mean, that you're using EF designer by "DB First"?

Comment: @Dennis the database existed before the code. The .edmx was generated from DB. When there is some schema change required, DB is changed first (using sql), then the edmx is updated (right click _Update Model from Database..._)

Comment: @Alireza can you be more specific please?

Comment: T4 Template + EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using designer, you can change visibility of setter from property grid. Just click on property, press F4, and select desired visibility:

[image]

But I recommend you to select `protected` instead of `private`, since there could be some difficulties (e.g. see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080521/the-key-component-id-is-not-a-declared-property-on-type-typename-when-using)).